# Man-pages don't include all relevant information

Tags: command-line, man, source

Consider the man-page of this function: `sysconf`  It doesn't have all the information that I need (e.g. all the system variables to be queried).

This is an example of what I need:

```
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html
```

Is there a  way to get around this problem without doing a search on some search-engines. I don't have access to the internet all the time, so this is exhaustive for me while reading source code.

Why the man-pages don't include all the information needed?

Comment: The opengroup documents are [free to download](https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/catalog/t101).

Comment: Because many of them are written by [one person](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git) and while they do an amazing job, they aren't superhuman. Patches welcome...